# Why is materialize not working with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-design, materialize

I created a static web page with materialize.css library, when I tried to move some components to react but they are not working.

This is my html boilerplate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script src="http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.13.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="button"></div>
    <script type=text/jsx src="main.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is main.js

```
var ButtomTest = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="test">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Stuff</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.render(
  <ButtomTest />,
  document.getElementById('button')
);
```

In the browser i only see "Stuff" in green color. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your spelling...

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language .

Comment: The docs imply that it requires JavaScript: http://materializecss.com/waves.html#! to work? Is it possible that because the button isn't rendered until after the `materialize.min.js` file is loaded, that it doesn't behave as expected?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I dont think so because Js load inline if I am not wrong, that line in jsx will be the same in html but I will try and comment here. Thanks

Comment: If the wave code isn't attaching to the DOM element, or it manipulates them unexpectedly, it's. It likely to work. Not every library is compatible with React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ensure that you are using `className` instead of `class` attribute in your jsx code.

Second, materialize.css uses [wave.js](http://www.plainconcepts.com/wavejs) to create a wave effect on button clicks and it doesn't fit quite well with react. But you can use [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui)`s Ripple [components](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/src/js/ripples) achieve the same effect

Comment: Where i have to add ClassName ?

Comment: Thanks i Figure out, inside <a ClassName>

Comment: @xzvkm It works okay, but you have to use componentDidMount to trigger whatever bindings to the JS that materialize-css uses... there are apparently some projects to deliver materialize-css as react components with appropriate bindings in place.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually had an easier time working with materializecss.com than any of the other tool kits.  However, I do this:

1) I do load the css via link at the main page, just because it's easier and doesn't seem to cause conflicts with other tools

2) So far, anytime anything doesn't work it's because I typed "class" instead of "className" (as you did in your example)

3) Sometimes you have to call the Materialize javascript object.   For example:

```
Materialize.Toast("a popup says what?",4000);
```

Luckily, because of how I load it I only have to amend that to:

```
window.Materialize.Toast("a popup says what?",4000);
```

My whole UI framework is simply materializecss.com + Mobx.
It's working out pretty well so far.