# How to make materialize Dropdown work in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

How do I make this materialize Dropdown work in React?

```
   <a className='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

   <ul id='dropdown1' className='dropdown-content'>
      <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
      <li className="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
   </ul>
```

[Materialize Dropdown documentation](http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html)

I've already included the materialize.js so that's taken care of. I'm guessing that it's something to do with the `data-activates` attribute. I'm not getting any error, but is there any other way to declare this attribute to make it work in React?

Comment: That's the way you declare data attributes. There must be something else going on.

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662350/why-is-materialize-not-working-with-reactjs

Comment: The problem you are facing is not because of react not allowing hyphen attributes. React allows data-* attributes (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html)

Without more information it is unclear what might be the problem though I believe it would be in including materialize properly.

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try dataActivates.

```
 <a className='dropdown-button btn' href='#' dataActivates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>
```

Ok, I found this at react.docs;

React supports all data-* and aria-* attributes as well as every attribute in the following lists.

Note:
All attributes are **camel-cased** and the attributes class and for are className and htmlFor, respectively, to match the DOM API specification.
For a list of events, see Supported Events.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Comment: dataActivates doesn't work, data-activates is valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropdown-button').dropdown({ 
                                inDuration: 300, 
                                outDuration: 225, 
                                constrain_width: true, 
                                hover: false, 
                                gutter: 0, 
                                belowOrigin: false 
                              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I ran into a number of issues using materializecss with React and spent far too long trying to find workarounds. Check out [React Materialize](https://react-materialize.github.io/#/dropdown), the link goes to their included Dropdown Component. Great library, simplifies things, and fixes a few other problems such as onClick handlers with some elements. You can also use them in together, and just add in React Materialize Components when you hit a road block.

Answer (score -3):

$('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
           inDuration: 300,
           outDuration: 225,
           constrain_width: true, 
           hover: false, 
           gutter: 0, 
           belowOrigin: false 
           }
      );

Comment: Hi Emel, instead adding the answer formated for a second time you shoud just edit it.